Find the repeated occurrence in a field using sort
Input:
 ----+----1----+----2----+  
 0112 CHENNAI             
 0104 HARRISON            
 0105 HARINI KRISHNAN     

Output:
----+----1----+----2----+----3----+
0112 CHENNAI         N             
0104 HARRISON        R             
0105 HARINI KRISHNAN H A R I N     

I tried with IFTHEN with Overlay but it doesn't work.
Can anyone help me with this?

It can be done, however it would require more than 1 pass of data.  The complexity of the job would depend on the length of the field in question. Answer the following questions

What is the LRECL and RECFM of the Input dataset ?
What is the length of the field that you want to repeat occurrence?
Would SPACE character would be considered as repeat character?



LRECL =80 and RECFM=FB  2] Length of the field is 15  Answer for Q3: no need to consider the SPACE as repeated characters    And one  more thing the Filed value can be varied i.e. we need to find the repeated characters in the field name and write into O/P file  Say for example I/P : 101 Harini Krishnan => O/P : Harini Krishnan  H A R I N  (here H A R I N are repeated characters in Name Field)


The following DFSORT/ICETOOL JCL will give you the desired results. The Repeating characters are shown at Position 81 on wards.
//STEP0100 EXEC PGM=ICETOOL                                        
//TOOLMSG  DD SYSOUT=*                                             
//DFSMSG   DD SYSOUT=*                                             
//INP      DD *                                                    
0112 CHENNAI                                                       
0104 HARRISON                                                      
0105 HARINI KRISHNAN                                               
0106 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO                                               
//TMP      DD DSN=&&TMP,DISP=(,PASS),SPACE=(CYL,(X,Y),RLSE)        
//OUT      DD SYSOUT=*                                             
//TOOLIN   DD *                                                    
  RESIZE FROM(INP) TO(TMP) TOLEN(80) USING(CTL1)                   
  SORT FROM(TMP) TO(OUT) USING(CTL2)                               
/*                                                  
//CTL1CNTL DD *                                                  
  OPTION COPY                                                    
  INREC IFOUTLEN=1201,                                           
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=INIT,                                       
             OVERLAY=(1201:06,15,SQZ=(SHIFT=LEFT))),             
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=INIT,                                       
               BUILD=(001,080,                                   
                      001,005,1201,001,74X,                      
                      001,005,1202,001,74X,                      
                      001,005,1203,001,74X,                      
                      001,005,1204,001,74X,                      
                      001,005,1205,001,74X,                      
                      001,005,1206,001,74X,                      
                      001,005,1207,001,74X,                      
                      001,005,1208,001,74X,                      
                      001,005,1209,001,74X,                      
                      001,005,1210,001,74X,                      
                      001,005,1211,001,74X,                      
                      001,005,1212,001,74X,                      
                      001,005,1213,001,74X,                      
                      001,005,1214,001,74X,                      
                      001,005,1215,001,74X))                     
                                                                 
  OUTFIL OMIT=(006,01,CH,EQ,C' '),                               
  IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,KEYBEGIN=(01,05),PUSH=(81:ID=8,90:SEQ=2)),  
  IFTHEN=(WHEN=INIT,OVERLAY=(93:C'00')),                         
  IFTHEN=(WHEN=(90,02,ZD,EQ,1),OVERLAY=(95:X'FF')),              
  IFTHEN=(WHEN=NONE,OVERLAY=(95:06,01,93:C'01'))                 
/*                                                               
//CTL2CNTL DD *                                                       
  SORT FIELDS=(81,08,CH,A,                                            
               95,01,CH,A),EQUALS                                     
                                                                      
   SUM FIELDS=(93,02,ZD)                                              
                                                                      
  OUTREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,BEGIN=(90,02,ZD,EQ,02,AND,93,02,ZD,GT,1), 
         END=(90,02,ZD,EQ,01),PUSH=(101:95,01)),                      
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,BEGIN=(90,02,ZD,EQ,03,AND,93,02,ZD,GT,1), 
         END=(90,02,ZD,EQ,01),PUSH=(103:95,01)),                      
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,BEGIN=(90,02,ZD,EQ,04,AND,93,02,ZD,GT,1), 
         END=(90,02,ZD,EQ,01),PUSH=(105:95,01)),                      
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,BEGIN=(90,02,ZD,EQ,05,AND,93,02,ZD,GT,1), 
         END=(90,02,ZD,EQ,01),PUSH=(107:95,01)),                      
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,BEGIN=(90,02,ZD,EQ,06,AND,93,02,ZD,GT,1), 
         END=(90,02,ZD,EQ,01),PUSH=(109:95,01)),                      
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,BEGIN=(90,02,ZD,EQ,07,AND,93,02,ZD,GT,1), 
         END=(90,02,ZD,EQ,01),PUSH=(111:95,01)),                      
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,BEGIN=(90,02,ZD,EQ,08,AND,93,02,ZD,GT,1), 
         END=(90,02,ZD,EQ,01),PUSH=(113:95,01)),                      
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,BEGIN=(90,02,ZD,EQ,09,AND,93,02,ZD,GT,1), 
         END=(90,02,ZD,EQ,01),PUSH=(115:95,01)),                      
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,BEGIN=(90,02,ZD,EQ,10,AND,93,02,ZD,GT,1), 
         END=(90,02,ZD,EQ,01),PUSH=(117:95,01)),                      
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,BEGIN=(90,02,ZD,EQ,11,AND,93,02,ZD,GT,1), 
         END=(90,02,ZD,EQ,01),PUSH=(119:95,01)),                      
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,BEGIN=(90,02,ZD,EQ,12,AND,93,02,ZD,GT,1), 
         END=(90,02,ZD,EQ,01),PUSH=(121:95,01)),                      
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,BEGIN=(90,02,ZD,EQ,13,AND,93,02,ZD,GT,1), 
         END=(90,02,ZD,EQ,01),PUSH=(123:95,01)),                      
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,BEGIN=(90,02,ZD,EQ,14,AND,93,02,ZD,GT,1), 
         END=(90,02,ZD,EQ,01),PUSH=(125:95,01)),                      
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,BEGIN=(90,02,ZD,EQ,15,AND,93,02,ZD,GT,1), 
         END=(90,02,ZD,EQ,01),PUSH=(127:95,01)),                      
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP,BEGIN=(90,02,ZD,EQ,16,AND,93,02,ZD,GT,1), 
         END=(90,02,ZD,EQ,01),PUSH=(129:95,01))                       
                                                                      
  OUTFIL REMOVECC,NODETAIL,                                           
  SECTIONS=(81,08,                                                    
  TRAILER3=(01,80,101,29))                                            
/*                                      

The output of this is
0112 CHENNAI                                                                          N    
0104 HARRISON                                                                       R      
0105 HARINI KRISHNAN                                                            H A R I N  
0106 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO                                                                       
                                         


Thank you so much for your effort and replying quicky....I tried with same sort card and it worked well..Thank you
